# Use sychronized or not below code generating same hashcode for all threads. How?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, singleton

"we make the global access method synchronized so that only one thread can execute getInstance method at a time" without using synchronized keyword below code acting like threadsafe already.

**Car.java**

```
public class Car {

private static Car car;

private Car() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public static Car getInstance(){
    if(car==null){
        car=new Car();
    }
    return car;
}
}
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Running");
            System.out.println(Car.getInstance().hashCode());
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Finishing");
        }
    });
    t1.start();

    Thread t2=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Running");
            System.out.println(Car.getInstance().hashCode());
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Finishing");
        }
    });

    t2.start();

    Thread t3=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Running");
            System.out.println(Car.getInstance().hashCode());
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Finishing");
        }
    });
    t3.start();
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Thread-0 Running
1828451009
Thread-0 Finishing
Thread-1 Running
1828451009
Thread-1 Finishing
Thread-2 Running
1828451009
Thread-2 Finishing
```

> Without using synchronized method hashcode are same in all thread case, how?

Comment: That is the hard part of thread safety: even thread-unsafe code may *seem* thread-safe if you observe it the wrong way. In your case the threads are simply executed one after another, there is no real multi threading happening at all in your case. If you write `t1.start(); t2.start(); t3.start();` you *may* see a different result.

Comment: tried this too but still unexpected output coming

Answer (score 0):

If i start all threads at a time

```
t1.start();
t2.start();
t3.start();
```

output is varying sometime same hashcode sometimes its different

```
Thread-1 Running
Thread-2 Running
Thread-0 Running
183297081
Thread-2 Finishing
183297081
Thread-1 Finishing
183297081
Thread-0 Finishing


Thread-0 Running
Thread-2 Running
Thread-1 Running
678111939
1828451009
1828451009
Thread-2 Finishing
Thread-1 Finishing
Thread-0 Finishing


Thread-0 Running
Thread-2 Running
Thread-1 Running
678111939
183297081
558529301
Thread-1 Finishing
Thread-2 Finishing
Thread-0 Finishing
```

**Unable to understand this behaviour**

Comment: That is **EXACTLY** what is expected: non-reproducible, weird, "unexpected" output. What more reason do you need to see that your code is **not** thread-safe?

Comment: yes got it, to maintain consistency in output we need synchronized method in singleton case. thanks @luk2302

Answer (score -1):

Thread scheduling is part of OS, if you execute the code several times you find differences. If you want your code thread safe in all cases then you have to use **synchroized** block with double locking.

```
public class Car {

    private static volatile Car car;

    private Car() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static Car getInstance(){
    if(car==null){
        synchronized(Car.class) {
           if(car==null)
            car=new Car();
        }
     }
    return car;
  }
}
```

> Note : Defining the whole method synchronized having performance
>   issue.

https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/05/double-checked-locking-on-singleton-in-java.html

Comment: Happy to help :) Mark it correct if it works with you

Comment: This code is **not** thread safe. This is a classic [DCL bug](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074979/java-concurrency/double-checked-locking--clever--but-broken.html).

Comment: volatile keyword could you used to avoid thread caching and written to main memory.

Comment: If you were to read the article, written by none other than Goetz, you'll find that this doesn't help unless every field in `Car` is also `volatile`. This answer is just wrong.